# How to use blender on Android

Tags: android

I want to develop a small game in Android. But for this I need to get animation into my Android project. Can I use blender to create animations and then port it into Android. If not then what other software can I use to create animation on Android. Are there any tutorials for this on the net.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With blender you can export your mesh/animation to a number of file formats. Your Android application must now be able to read the file format you have exported the animation with. A common file format blender is capable of to export is `.obj`. [This](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16551) article describes the implementation of an `.obj` file loader.

[This](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg2/jogles2/JOGL-ES2.pdf) is an excellent example for an mesh loader.

[Here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/435493/Android/Mobile/Importing-models-Android) you can find some other links.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can play with blender animations in Unity3D which runs on Android

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same : animate in blender and be able to do a 3D app for Android.
I ended up choosing Unity3D which is really great : you build your animation in Blender and you export it to Unity. Then in Unity you can code your application and export a .apk :)

Cheers,
bRo